# Azure DevOps: release version

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, software-design

I am going to create my CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps, but I have a problem with release version number. with this CI/CD a dotnet app build and a docker image created, so I want to have docker image release number same as : V1.2.0 and ..... but currently I have number for example: 10, 11, ... or only the latest tag!
Can anybody support me to have my own release version number ?
Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases

Comment: You can use our SaaS solution to keep control of versions - be it semver, calver or something custom; it integrates with any CI/CD platform - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could set the release version number in **Release Pipelines -> Options -> General -> Release name format**.

[image]

The `$(rev:r)` is an incrementing variable. So you could add it in the Release version.

For example: `V1.2.$(rev:r)`

Result:

[image]

Note: the `$(rev:r)` counts from 1 (1,2,3...).

From your requirement, you are using CI and CD process and it seems that you need to count from 0. You also could try to use the $(Build.buildnumber) variable.

Here are the steps:

Step1: In Build Pipeline(CI) , set the count variable(e.g. `BuildRevision :$[counter( ' ',0)]`).

[image]

Step2: Use the variable in Build number (Build Pipeline->Options ->Build number format).

[image]

Step3: Set the build artifacts as the release source. Use the $(Build.buildnumber) in release pipeline version.

[image]

Result:

[image]

In this situation, the release version could start from v1.2.0.

**Update:**

> when I change the release version for example from V0.0 to V1.0 , how the counter restarted ?

You could try the following steps:

Create 2 variables:

1.`major-minor = 0.0`

2.`revision = $[ counter(variables['major-minor'],0) ]`

The build number:  `$(major-minor).$(revision)`

In this case, when the `major-minor` change as V1.0, the counter will reset.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, What I did is : defining 2 variables : BuildRevision:V0.0 and BuildRevisionCounter : $[counter(' ',0)], so it works properly. My question is, when I change the release version for example from V0.0 to V1.0 , how the counter restarted ?

Comment: Hi @MerajKashi. Please check the update. When you change the  variable , the counter will restart.

Comment: I wish I could find this great idea 3 years ago, before creating Release Pipelines for specific public facing DLLs just because I needed release numbers integrated into the assemblies.

Comment: Really like the idea !
For people in need: We intended to use GitVersion but the build pipeline failed constantly after adding it to our project >> wheras variables in pipeline works perfectly

Comment: How to do this with yaml / non classic pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use GitVersion and Semantic Versioning pattern.
For that you will need this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion

After that you add the step before compiling/build your project:

```
steps:
 - task: GitVersion@5
   inputs:
      runtime: 'core'
```

After that you can use variable:

> $(GitVersion.FullSemVer)

That variable will store the current build version - it's based on git.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. As we use Azure Repos, so does this extension work in my case?

Comment: I use it with Azure Repos, Pipelines etc. it works fine.